# PHP auto-fill selectbox through URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a question I can't figure out.

```
<?php
                $killtheboy = 0;
if($killtheboy == 1){
    echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"dwanummer\" id=\"dwanummer\">";
}else{

    echo "<div id=\"dropdowndwa\">
                <select name=\"dwanummer\" id=\"dwanummer\" class=\"dwanummer\">
                <option selected=\"selected\">Kies uit lijst</option>";
                include("config/instellingen.php");
                $query = "SELECT DISTINCT `Klantvraag`,`Wensweek` FROM `DWA` WHERE `Status DWA` = 'DBAA' OR `Status DWA` = 'DBAP' OR `Status DWA` = 'DIUI' ORDER BY wensweek - '$wensweekber' ASC";
                if ($result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)) {
                while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $week = date('W', strtotime("this week"));
                    $jaar = date('Y', strtotime("this week"));
                    $wens =  ''. $jaar . ''. $week. '';
                    $wensweek = $get['Wensweek'];
                    $wensweekber = $wensweek - $wens;
                    echo '<div class="selectBlock"><option value="' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '" name="dwanummer" id="dwanummer" class="dwanummer">'.$get['Klantvraag'] . ' Wensweek :  ' . $wensweekber . '</option></div>';
                         }
                }
                    echo "</select></div><br />";
}
?>
```

The above code (PHP) fetches a list of numbers on pageload and I have to select one in order to fetch that information through JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $(".kvraagnummer").change(function()
   {
   var id = $("#kvraagnummer option:selected").prop("value");
   var dataString = 'id=' + id;

   $.ajax
   ({
   type: "POST",
    url: "add_event_2.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $('.cnummer').html(html);
   } 
   });

   });
   });
   </script>
```

Basically I have a search system and u can find all 'cases' there and if you see one you want then you click it it goes to the above page with code and it auto selects that ID instead of still having to select it. (like additem.php?id=125533 or something)

Can someone please explain me how I can solve this.

Comment: To author and future reader: Above code has some gaping SQL *and* XSS security holes.

Comment: Any suggestions ? or comments I can use the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this, You need to use `selected` attribute in `select` element

```
    $Selected =''; 
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && ($get['Klantvraag'] == $_GET['id'])){          
        $Selected =" selected='selected' ";
    }

    echo '<option value="' . $get['Klantvraag'] . '"   '.$Selected.'  name="dwanummer" id="dwanummer" class="dwanummer">'.$get['Klantvraag'] . ' Wensweek :  ' . $wensweekber . '</option>';
```

Javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
       $(".kvraagnummer").change(function()
       {
           Populate();

       });

       Populate();
   });

   function Populate(){
       var id = $("#kvraagnummer option:selected").prop("value");
       var dataString = 'id=' + id;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: "add_event_2.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(html)
           {
            $('.cnummer').html(html);

                 removeAllNameSelectBoxes();
                 var selected = $("#dropdowndwa option:selected").map(function (i, el) {
                 return el.value;
    }).get();

                        getNamesFromSelectIds(selected);
           } 
       });

   }
```